# Different results while calculating eigenvectors with Gaussian elemination

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Regarding this matrix $\begin{matrix}
  1 &  1  \\
  1 &-1 \\
 \end{matrix}$. In the end I have to solve this equation system:

$(\sqrt2-1)x_1-x_2=0$

$-x_1+(\sqrt2+1)x_2=0$

While the eigenvector is $x_1=1$ and $x_2=\sqrt2-1$, I can't seem to get the result using Gaussian elemination. It is always $x_1=0$ and $x_2 =0$.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the system $(\sqrt 2 I - A)\vec x = \vec 0$ by row reducing the augmented matrix, we obtain:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
\sqrt 2 - 1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & \sqrt 2 + 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\sim
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & -\sqrt 2 - 1 & 0 \\
\sqrt 2 - 1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\sim
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & -\sqrt 2 - 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence, since $x_1 = (\sqrt 2 + 1)x_2$, we obtain:
$$
\vec x
= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} (\sqrt 2 + 1)x_2 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}
= x_2\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 2 + 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $x_2$ is any nonzero scalar. In particular, taking $x_2 = \sqrt 2 - 1$ yields the eigenvector that you want.

Comment: Could you please tell, how did you get zeroes in the second line of your third matrix?

Comment: Multiply the second row by $(\sqrt 2 + 1)$, then add it to the first row. Remember that when row-reducing $[\lambda I - A \mid 0]$, you will **always** get a row of zeroes somewhere.